# Font does not appear to be being applied Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, fonts, google-font-api

I am working on a website for a customer creating my own theme for them, but I cant understand why the fonts are not registring it appears to be still in arial or something instead of robot but I have added the google font in my head its bringing the site into wordpress from flat php

Code i used to add robot is

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300italic,300,100italic,100,900italic,900,700italic,700,500italic,400italic,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

wordpress version http://webservices.davidbuckleyni.co.uk/wordpress/?page_id=8

live site
http://www.key2credit.com/

their is also a space above where the banner is im thinking i missing a reset script or something

**Edit** My bad here is the css showing the font being used for body 
  However i think its just the text within the main banner thats amiss ie where it says Fast cash loans

```
body {
padding-top: 120px;
padding-bottom:38px;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
background: url("./.fs/img/banner2.jpg") repeat;
}
```

**Edit to show here in head im calling this style sheet to reference the font**

/wordpress/wp-content/themes/key2credit/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `h2` (and possibly your other header) tag styles are being overridden (as they're showing as `inherit` (or maybe another parent element it's contained within).

Try to specifically target the text in your banner. Add this to your CSS declaration on line 428 of `style.css`:

```
.homeBanner .homeBannerContent {
    margin-top: 4%;
    height: 315px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Your text issue is quite simply happening because the block of T&Cs is set as `position:absolute;bottom;0;left;0;` meaning, it will float to the bottom left of it's parent container.

It's parent container is the `.homeBannerContent` div, which doesn't go down to the bottom of the banner. What I'd do, is take the T&Cs text, outside of the home banner content, and make the main banner div has `position:relative;`. That should stick it to the bottom left of the banner itself.

Or simply remove the `position:absolute;bottom:0;left;0;` properties from the CSS of the T&Cs box, and have it display as a standard block.

Comment: that seem to help with font but still a gap bigger between banner and nav and the paragraph is messed up still grr i hate css love desktop development

Comment: I don't see an issue with gaps between the banner and navigation.

Comment: I mean its the text crunched up well that alow it looks like with me see way secure is not in right position and the small paragraph text? http://awesomescreenshot.com/0615a62g38

Comment: You mean at the bottom of the banner? The T&Cs?

Comment: Representative 728.9% APR.

Representative example: Borrowing £400 over 30 days, total repayable £459.36. Interest charged is £59.35, interest rate 180.5% (variable). that bit below the tag line in the banner